# Jquery only alpha-numeric characters not fixed sized

Tags: jquery

I am using  [Jquery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)

I need to change the patern below, to one that accepts only alpha-numeric characters .

I need to eliminate any other kind of character, white spaces, quotes or double-quotes.

I will not have a fixed length size, it can vary from 6 until 10

```
$('.carPlates').mask('AAA0000', {'translation': {
        A: {pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/},
        0: {pattern: /[0-9*]/}
      }
});
```

I find this regex pattern that accepts only alpha-numeric characters :

```
/[\W_]+/u
```

How can i use this pattern and allow from 6 until 10 characters ?

Comment: add `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: and for the first parameter : 'AAA0000' what will be this first parameter to accept 6 from 10 characters ?

Comment: Thank you @Meraj Hhan i implement it :  $('.plateGeneral').mask('0000000000', {'translation': {

            0: {pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/}            
          } 
    });

Comment: if it is useful accept answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$('.carPlates').mask('0000000000', {'translation': { 
        0: {pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/} 
   }
 });
```